# EntityFramework Core get multiple results after join

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

The database has tables Machines, Wheels, Characteristics. 
1 record of the car includes 4 records of a wheel and several characteristics. In the database, it looks something like this:[image]

I want to get the last 5 entries about cars, including a complete set of parameter data and wheel information. And I would like to get all the data in one request.

```
 var result = (from Machines in db.Machines.Where(x => x.param == 2) orderby Machines.ID descending
                      join wheel in db.Wheels on Machines.ID equals wheel.MachineId
                      join param in db.Characteristcs on Machines.ID equals param.MachineId
                      select new { Machines, param, wheel } 
                      ).Take(5).ToList();
```

but it returns only one wheel record and one characteristic.

Comment: Don't use joins. Use proper relations between the entities and let the ORM generate the joins. That's its job

Comment: What's your model class code and the screenshot of the actual result? I created a demo for test based on your screenshot and code, it got the excepted result . You could refer to my reply below.

Comment: @TiyebM *"The idea of creating a query and executing it without needing predefined navigation rules is strong, and should be addressed by the framework itself; Not only **Include**.` The idea of navigation properties is much stronger and is always preferred over manual joins, and especially for things that represent relationships as in this case. Because they are much more than supporting `Include`. When used in queries, they allow ORM to create the joins, and developer concentrating of the query logic using the more natural object oriented approach. Joins are RDBMS (SQL) feature, and...

Comment: ...the only reason they exist in LINQ is because LINQ to **Objects** needs them for efficient implementation of the correlated operations. EF Core does not need them at all - correlated `Where` and `DefaultIfEmpty` are enough to generate the appropriate SQL joins when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EF Core, you could refer to the [relationship](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) and [load raleted data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) for more details.

Here is my working demo :

*Model*

```
public class Machines
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public int Param { get; set; }
}
public class Characteristics
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Parameter { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int MachineId { get; set; }
}
public class Wheels
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Radius { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public int MachineId { get; set; }
}
```

*Controller*

```
public IActionResult GetCars()
{
        var collection = (from Machines in _context.Machines.Where(x => x.Param == 2)
                      join wheel in _context.Wheels on Machines.Id equals wheel.MachineId
                      join param in _context.Characteristics on Machines.Id equals param.MachineId
                      select new { Machines, param, wheel }
                  ).ToList();

        //get the last 5 entries about cars
        var result= collection.Skip(Math.Max(0, collection.Count() - 5)).ToList();
        return new JsonResult(result);
}
```

Comment: This loads the whole collection (table) in memory just to take 5 items needed. Don't use such code in general (it works only for small tables with few fields), there are better solutions depending of the EFC version used.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should see first if your model has defined Navigation Properties to the entities you need:

```
public class Machine {

  public int ID {get;set;}
  //...
  //Navigation Properties
  public IList<Wheel> Wheels {get;set;}
  public IList<Charateristic> Charateristics {get;set;}

}
```

If that is the case your query would be:

```
var query= context.Machines.Include(m=> m.Wheels)
                           .Include(m=>m.Charateristics)
                           .Where(x => x.param == 2)
                           .Take(5)
                           .ToList();
```

The `Include` methods help to build a query fetching the data you need from the related table.

In case you haven't defined navigation properties, which I strongly recommend to do, you can do [group joins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-grouped-joins)

```
var query=  from m in context.Machines
            join c in context.Charateristics on m.Id equals c.MachineId into gc
            join w in context.Wheels on m.Id equals w.MachineId into gw
            select new {Machine= m, Wheels= gw, Charateristics=gc };

var result= query.Take(5).ToList();
```

Comment: Good answer in *general* or *EF6*, but EF Core (till now, will see what happens in next versions) always has its own treatments of LINQ query translation. The "little" problem here is that group joins are not supported in EFC 3.x - 5.x, so the second part simply doesn't work (runtime exception).

Answer (score 2):

1. In SQL Server, create Machine's relationships with Wheels and Characteristic tables.
2. Re-run scaffolding-dbcontext to update your EF dbcontext and models
3. Use Include linq. 
   var result = db.Machines.Where(x => x.Id == 2).Include(x => x.Wheels).Include(x => x.Characteristics);

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDMcF.png)